# Access to particular item in a List<Map> in Dart

Tags: arrays, object, flutter, dart

how can I access to a particular item in a `List <Map>` with Dart?..
Doing an analogy with JS it's would be something like `arrayObject[0].atribObject`... Example

I need to show the value of `name` atrib from 2nd object

```
List<Map> arrayObjects = [{"name":"Map1"},{"name":"Map2"}];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well since it's a list of maps the correct syntax would be:

```
List<Map> arrayObjects = [{"name":"Map1"},{"name":"Map2"}];

print(arrayObjects[1]["name"]);
```

Comment: Yes I marked, but I'm new here and the messages was this "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."